# What algorithm could I use to compare GPS progress along a route compared to a previous GPS trace?

Tags: algorithm, gps, geolocation, real-time

I am looking to implement something similar to Strava's live segments feature. I will try to explain briefly.

Here is an example cycle segment.

https://www.strava.com/segments/610040

Simply, it is an ordered list of known GPS co-ordinates which make up a route. Via Strava's API it is possible to retrieve all of your attempts at this route (the parts of your cycles deemed to have followed the route closely enough).

The GPS trace for my best effort might look like:

```
[{
    time: "13:30.01",
    lat: 38.603734,
    lon: -122.864112
},
{
    time: "13:30.03",
    lat: 38.608798,
    lon: -122.867714
},
{
    time: "13:30.06",
    lat: 38.604691,
    lon: -122.88178
}]
```

Now, say I am out for a cycle and have an app tracking my current location. I am looking to do a live comparison between the current cycle and the known "best" attempt (e.g. you are 5 seconds down).

I'm not really sure where to start or if there is a Google-able term which would provide similar examples of what I'm trying to accomplish without me re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: "I'm not really sure what Google-able term I'm missing" ...  this makes me sad...

Comment: Well, I meant that perhaps this is something which has been done many times before and there is a better way of describing what I'm trying to do.